# symfony routing problem

Tags: routes, symfony1

I have mp3 catalog portal and I want to customize my urls.
I used url for downloading songs - /download/song/:song_id
But now I want url to look like /download/song:song_id - symfony doesn't recognize this pattern, :song_id parameter substitutes in url as is, so I get /download/song:song_id instead of f.e. /download/song14

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved via adding empty separator_segment:
options: { segment_separators: [/, ., -, ''] }

Comment: How does this code work? Can you explain where you added this piece of code?